# Mysql full text search exact match with no other words

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a mysql fulltext search,
I set a Score value for order the results by corrispondance, my problem is I would like to give a better score to records that match 100% the keywords

if i search for "the da vinci code", I use the query

```
SELECT Title, MATCH('title') AGAINST ('("the da vinci code") the vinci code' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as Score FROM books WHERE  MATCH('title') AGAINST ('("the da vinci code") the vinci code' IN BOOLEAN MODE) HAVING Score>=2 ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

The problem is that if I have books named "The da vinci code, the ultimate guide" or 'Illustrated guide to the da vinci code', they get the same score as the most relevant i want, the "the da vinci code' by Dan Brown...

Any ideas how i could invent a better Score for the exact match without any other words?

Answer (score -1):

Use NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE instead of BOOLEAN MODE